# Redirect from Observer to home page?

Tags: magento2.3

I want to redirect to the home page (xyx.com) using the observer object & i am using the event `controller_action_predispatch_cms_index_index`.

below syntax is working fine when moving to the login page by the observer, Even I can move to any custom URL with the help of an observer object but unable to redirect to the home page.

below code is just for example.
$observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect('customer/account/login');

I have tried many solutions:

**Try Solution 1 :**

```
$observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect('home');
```

but it will redirect to xyz.com/home

**Try Solution 2:**
(a) `$Url = $this->url->getUrl('');` OR (b) `$Url = $this->url->getBaseUrl();`  or (c) `$Url = $this->url->getUrl('/');`

& pass $Url to setRedirect but that is also not working.

```
 $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($Url);
```

My Question is how to pass home page address to setRedirect.

**Updated**: Don't know the getUrl behaviour. Everthing thing is working & even custom url also working on getUrl on passing on observer & i am able to redirect anywhere accpording to my wish.

```
  $url =  getUrl('custom/url') or getUrl('home')
     or getUrl('customer/account/login')
```

all the above are working on setRedirect => `$observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);`

but $url =  getUrl() is not working.

Does anyone face the same issue on redirection from observer. ?

Comment: Please check and update me.

Comment: Not working I want to redirect to home page (i.e xyz.com) but  $myUrl = $this->url->getUrl('home'); echo $myUrl will give this path xyz.com/home

Comment: &  $this->url->getUrl(); is the home page url & when i pass on setRedirect. It is not working

Comment: please check my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324428/82670

Answer (score 1):

**Seems like you want to redirect Home page's cms page to Website index php**

means redirect to `xyz.com/home` to `xyz.com`.

First, lets understand the router logic for these pages.

When You have hit `xyz.com/home` it called the Cms router  `Magento\Cms\Controller\Router` and which hit the `\Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View` action

Where, You have hit `xyz.com/`  its does not call the Cms router  `Magento\Cms\Controller\Router` and it directly `\Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index` action

So, if you want to redirect `/home` to **index page**. then you have to work on  on `\Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View::execute`

Create an aroud plugin on it and redirect to home page.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackExchanges\CmsRedirect\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Cms\Controller\Page;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class View
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    private $resultRedirectFactory;
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface  $url,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
    ){

        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Cms\Controller\Page\View $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $homePageCmsPageId = 1;
        $id = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('page_id') ?  $subject->getRequest()->getParam('id'):false;
        if($id!== 1){
            $result = $proceed();
        }
        $result = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl(
            $this->url->getBaseUrl()
        );
        return $result;
    }
}
```

### Update

You need to add FLAG_NO_DISPATCH on this observer.

```
<?php


namespace StackExchanges\CmsRedirect;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Redirect implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var ActionFlag
     */
    private $actionFlag;
    /**
     * @var RedirectInterface
     */
    private $redirect;
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        RedirectInterface $redirect,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Action $controller */
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->actionFlag->set('', Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit,  thanks for the valuable answer & understand the router logic. Actually I am using controller_action_predispatch_cms_index_index according to requirement. And I want to restrict the home page for some user or group id (Who is not the customer). They are merchants so that they can't access the home page after login. And I am able to do this & now the merchant can't access the home page.

But the problem occurs when no one is login & simply I open the homepage & it redirects me to xyz.com/home & I have tried the different solutions but did not get success.

Comment: Pankaj, first, please your question properly. You question and  comment are different .

Comment: yes but i want to know in my question why below code is not working $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->url->getBaseUrl());

Comment: After adding $this->actionFlag->set('', Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true); still recursion happen & Due to many redirect on homepage 500 internal error.

Answer (score 1):

controller_action_predispatch_cms_index_index is the Home page predispatch & it is called always whenever the homepage hit by a User or it is called at the time of logout after a few seconds, when user come back to the homepage.

And this is not logical to redirect the same action But sometimes there is a requirement when we need to do this.

In Short words, In my question, I was asking why was $this->getUrl() is not working in $observer method.

```
i.e $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl());
```

& I have done so many tried solution which are working inside setRedirect but expect homepage Url. Now I got to know why this is happening.

hahahaha... Reason: Due to recursion or you can say that

```
function abc() {
     abc();
}

abc();
```

I know, I did a very silly mistake & I am posting this as my answer so that no one can do this again.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $responseFactory;
protected $url;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ...
) {
    $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $myUrl = $this->url->getUrl('home'); //Get url of cms page
    $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($myUrl)->sendResponse(); 
    die(); //This will stop execution and redirect to specific page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution 2 did not work ? what `$Url` returns ?
Did you try to put `'/'` instead of `'home'` ?
if you put `'home'` it calls the cms page called `'home'`.

Comment: try this one also, now updated.  (c) $Url = $this->url->getUrl('/');

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class YourObserverName implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        ........................................................
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ........................................................

    ) {
        ........................................................
        $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
        ........................................................
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $url = $this->getHomeUrl();
        $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        return $this;
    } 

    public function getHomeUrl()
    {
        $link = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_LINK);
        return $link;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the code inside the getHomeUrl() function is equivalent to getUrl('Home') OR  getBaseUrl('Home'). I have tried this also but it is redirecting xyz.com/home instead of xyz.com

Comment: @PankajPant I updated the answer. please check and update me.